# Include static files in installed directory

Tags: python, python-3.x, setuptools

I have the following directory structure:

```
/mypackage
    __init__.py
    setup.py
    code.py
    MANIFEST.in
    /static
        app.js
```

In `setup.py` I've tried any combination of `MANIFEST.in`, `data_files`, `package_data`, `include_package_data=True`.

I'm able to make the setup include `static/app.js` in the `.tar.gz` file generated by running `python setup.py sdist`, but I'm not able in any way to get `pip install` to actually distribute the static files in the installed directory.

All I want is basically to replicate the source structure into the installed directory.

The closes I could get is to have the setup to add a `static` directory into the *root* of site_packages as if the static files were another package. In short, I want to get the following structure into `site_packages`

```
/site_packages
    /mypackage
        __init__.py
        code.py
        /static
            app.js
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your developemt directory structure is wrong. It must be the same as installed package:

```
/mypackage
    setup.py
    MANIFEST.in
    /mypackage
        __init__.py
        code.py
        /static
            app.js
```

`setup.py`:

```py
setup (
    packages = ['mypackage'],
    package_data = {
        'mypackage': ['static/app.js']
    },
    ...
)
```

Now generate distributions: `python.setup.py sdist bdist_wheel`